# Running visual studio using cmd fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I tried to use the cmd command to run Visual Studio. I cd to the path where deven.exe is located in cmd. Everything here is normal, but when I start deven.exe, a warning of insufficient permissions is prompted. I queried Google. Some answers recommended that I change the Group Policy of the Windows system, but I am using Windows 10 Home Edition and did not find options related to Group Policy. Are there any other solutions besides this method?

Comment: Can you start it from the Start menu?

Comment: This is OK, but I want to start some exe through cmd, so I use vs to test

Comment: You can try to right -click before opening CMD and click "Run As Administrator"

Comment: I didn't know that I could open cmd like this before. However, I noticed that not all exe locations require administrator rights. This may be related to the privacy settings of Windows.

Comment: @Sadenforen Hi, I published a answer in combination with my comments. If it help you, you can make its mark so that it can help more people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to right -click before opening CMD and click "Run As Administrator"

If your deven.exe will face the situation of insufficient permissions when the CMD command is used, because the C drive will have a different protection mechanism from other disks as a system disk